# How to extract table and text from docx?

Tags: python, data-scrubbing

I am working on extracting text and tables from Docx files using pydocx library. I have to extract text and tables separately from the doc file that is creating issue of linking tabular data with text content.

```
e.g.

text

There are two types of merchant roles:  standard merchant and admin merchant. The standard merchant user will be a subset of the admin merchant user. The app will be common for both roles but component visibility will differ based on the merchant type. The following table defines access control for different merchant roles:

Table
Module  Standard Merchant   Admin Merchant
Login   Y   Y
Register    NA  Y
Dashboard   Y   Y
Voucher List    N   Y
Create Voucher  N   Y
Scan Voucher    N   N
Personal Details    Y   Y
Bank Details    N   Y
Setup Team  N   Y
Notifications   Y   Y
Change Password Y   Y
Help & Support  Y   Y
Privacy Policy  Y   Y
```

I want to extract above data in a single call. Is that possible?